# DAE with mass matrix in python

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

a system like

M*y' = y

where M is singular, can be solved easily with Matlabs ode23. In my case M is konstant.

I found PyDStools, it should be possible to use DASSL e.g in FORTRAN or C++. All of them are pretty complex and not very intuitive. (at least for me)

Had someone the same challenge and can point me to a good point to start with ?

I guess i cannot do something like:
y' = np.linalg.inv(M)*y

and use this equation with scipy.integrate and the vode solver ?

Comment: well, i found: https://github.com/jwallen/PyDAS

Comment: This one is quite nicely documented:
http://www.jmodelica.org/assimulo_home/tutorial_imp.html

Comment: Moritz, I encountered a similar problem, Can you hepl me? Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72386143/is-there-a-function-in-sympy-or-scipy-that-corresponds-to-massmatrixform-in-matl