# Is there a function in sympy or scipy that corresponds to massMatrixForm in matlab?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I am learning rigid body kinematics from:
https://rotations.berkeley.edu/the-poisson-top-with-friction/ .
The link to the matlab source code is at the bottom of the page.
Derive the Poisson top’s equations of motion:
http://rotations.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/derive_poisson_top_ODEs.txt
Solve the Poisson top’s equations of motion:
http://rotations.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/solve_poisson_top_ODEs.txt

```
%  Express the state equations in mass-matrix form, M(t,Y)*Y'(t) = F(t,Y):

[Msym, Fsym] = massMatrixForm(StateEqns, StateVars);

Msym = simplify(Msym)
Fsym = simplify(Fsym)

%  Convert M(t,Y) and F(t,Y) to symbolic function handles with the input 
%  parameters specified:

M = odeFunction(Msym, StateVars, m, g, lambdat, lambdaa, L3, muk);  
F = odeFunction(Fsym, StateVars, m, g, lambdat, lambdaa, L3, muk); 

%  Save M(t,Y) and F(t,Y):

save poisson_top_ODEs.mat Msym Fsym StateVars M F
```

I rewrote most of the code for the derivation process in python, though may not be elegant code.

```
from sympy import * 
from sympy.physics.mechanics import *
from sympy.physics.vector import vlatex
import os
os.system('cls')

psi, theta, phi, Dpsi, Dtheta, Dphi, D2psi, D2theta, D2phi = dynamicsymbols('psi theta phi Dpsi Dtheta Dphi D2psi D2theta D2phi') 
x1, x2, x3, Dx1, Dx2, Dx3, D2x1, D2x2, D2x3 = dynamicsymbols('x1 x2 x3 Dx1 Dx2 Dx3 D2x1 D2x2 D2x3') 
m, g, lambdat, lambdaa, L3 = symbols('m g lambdat lambdaa L3') #, real=True, positive=True) 
muk = symbols('muk', real=True) 

R1 = Matrix([[cos(psi), sin(psi), 0],        
      [-sin(psi), cos(psi), 0],
      [0, 0, 1]])  

R2 = Matrix([[1, 0, 0],
      [0, cos(theta), sin(theta)],
      [0, -sin(theta), cos(theta)]])

R3 = Matrix([[cos(phi), sin(phi), 0],
      [-sin(phi), cos(phi), 0],
      [0, 0, 1]])  

tmp1=Matrix([0, 0, diff(psi,'t')])
tmp2=Matrix([diff(theta,'t'), 0, 0])
tmp3=Matrix([0, 0, diff(phi,'t')])

omega = simplify((R3*R2*R1)*tmp1 + (R3*R2)*tmp2 + R3*tmp3)
# print(vlatex(omega))

vP = simplify(Matrix([Dx1, Dx2, Dx3]) - transpose(R3*R2*R1)*(omega.cross(Matrix([0, 0, L3]))))
# print(vlatex(vP))

tmp1 = Matrix([1, 0, 0]).T
tmp2 = Matrix([0, 1, 0]).T
tmp3 = Matrix([0, 0, 1]).T

vP1 = tmp1.dot(vP)
vP2 = tmp2.dot(vP)
# print(vP1,vP2)

vCOM = simplify(Matrix([vP1, vP2, 0]) + transpose(R3*R2*R1)*(omega.cross(Matrix([0, 0, L3]))))
# print(vlatex(vCOM))

Dx3 = tmp3.dot(vCOM)
# print(Dx3)

omega = omega.subs([(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi)])
# print_latex(omega)

vP1 = vP1.subs([(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi)])
vP2 = vP2.subs([(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi)])
Dx3 = Dx3.subs([(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi)])

vP = simplify(sqrt(vP1**2 + vP2**2))
# print(vP1,vP2,vP,Dx3)

N = m*diff(Dx3,'t') + m*g
F1 = -muk*N*vP1/vP
F2 = -muk*N*vP2/vP
# print(vlatex(F1))

eq1 = Eq(m*diff(Dx1,'t'), F1).subs([(diff(Dx1,'t'),D2x1),(diff(Dx2,'t'),D2x2)])
eq2 = Eq(m*diff(Dx2,'t'), F2).subs([(diff(Dx1,'t'),D2x1),(diff(Dx2,'t'),D2x2)])

H = diag(lambdat, lambdat, lambdaa)*omega
omegaRF = omega

DH = diff(H,'t') + omegaRF.cross(H)

sumM = Matrix([0, 0, -L3]).cross((R3*R2*R1)*Matrix([F1, F2, N]))

tmp1=Matrix([[sin(phi), -cos(phi), 0],
            [cos(phi), sin(phi), 0],
            [0, 0, 1]])

DHt = tmp1*DH
sumMt = tmp1*sumM

eq3 = Eq(DHt[0,0],sumMt[0,0])
eq4 = Eq(DHt[1,0],sumMt[1,0])
eq5 = Eq(DHt[2,0],sumMt[2,0])

eq1 = simplify(eq1.subs(
      [(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi),
      (diff(Dpsi,'t'), D2psi), (diff(Dtheta,'t'), D2theta), (diff(Dphi,'t'), D2phi)]))

eq2 = simplify(eq2.subs(
      [(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi),
      (diff(Dpsi,'t'), D2psi), (diff(Dtheta,'t'), D2theta), (diff(Dphi,'t'), D2phi)]))

eq3 = simplify(eq3.subs(
      [(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi),
      (diff(Dpsi,'t'), D2psi), (diff(Dtheta,'t'), D2theta), (diff(Dphi,'t'), D2phi)]))

eq4 = simplify(eq4.subs(
      [(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi),
      (diff(Dpsi,'t'), D2psi), (diff(Dtheta,'t'), D2theta), (diff(Dphi,'t'), D2phi)]))

eq5 = simplify(eq5.subs(
      [(diff(psi,'t'), Dpsi), (diff(theta,'t'), Dtheta), (diff(phi,'t'), Dphi),
      (diff(Dpsi,'t'), D2psi), (diff(Dtheta,'t'), D2theta), (diff(Dphi,'t'), D2phi)]))

res = solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5],[D2psi, D2theta, D2phi, D2x1, D2x2])

print('--------')
print(vlatex(res))
```

In fact, it is impossible to solve the expressions of D2psi, D2theta, D2phi, D2x1 and D2x2, which are the first order differential form of the equations of motion, with sympy.solve.

Is there a function in sympy or scipy that corresponds to massMatrixForm in matlab? Or something like that? So I can rewrite this simulation in python by using solve_ivp.

Comment: This borders on the "recommend" kind of question.   At least give an link to the MATLAB function docs, and explain what you want, maybe even a [mcve].  While it wasn't hard to find those docs, I should have to do that.  Off hand this looks like a symbolic task, not a numeric one, though the example does use `ode15s`.  `scipy` has numeric ode solvers, but `sympy` is required for the symbolic stuff.  While there may be someone who can give you a quick answer, my sense is this too big/broad a question for SO.  You need to do a lot more homework first.

Comment: Thanks.
In fact it is a mixed symbolic + numeric task.
First, the kinematic equations of the top are found using symbolic calculations. Then numerical calculations are used to calculate the trajectory of the top.

For a relatively simple motion, such as a pendulum, or a top without considering friction, we can use sympy to derive a set of differential equations in the form of "first-order" differentials. Then it is easy to use scipy's solve_ivp to calculate the motion trajectory.

Comment: However, in this example, the system of differential equations cannot be represented in first-order form by symbolic calculations due to the introduction of friction.

matlab provides a solution in this case, which is the massMatrixForm function (as  mentioned in my question) and ode15s.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/massmatrixform.html

And from the documentation of matlab, it is a DAE problem rather than an ODE problem. So I was wondering if the same thing could be achieved using sympy+scipy.

Comment: MATLAB integrates the symbolic and numeric well. sympy and numpy interact with `lambdify` if at all.

Comment: Thanks. But for me I had another difficulty other than lambdify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to test your code right now, but I believe you are looking for the `linear_eq_to_matrix` function.

Replace the `solve` command with the following:

```
A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5],[D2psi, D2theta, D2phi, D2x1, D2x2])
```

Comment: It's also necessary to replace the derivatives with ordinary symbols like `eq1.subs({theta.diff(): z, ...})` but after that `linear_eq_to_matrix` will work.

Comment: Hi, Davide and Oscar, Thank you very much. I'll try it later.

Comment: linear_eq_to_matrix does succeed in giving results, although I don't know if it's correct yet.
But I'm a little confused because in the sympy documentation it mentions that "Here  must be a linear system of equations in symbols" for linear_eq_to_matrix method， however,  I don't think the system of equations is linear.

Comment: Hi, Davide and Oscar， How can I use A and b directly in scipy? It looks like it is not practical to solve for A **-1 *b， but solve_ivp requires this form.

Comment: @nicholasfor you have to compute `dydt = A.inv() * b`, then you use `lambdify([s1, s2, ...], dydt)` (with `s1, s2, ...` symbols) to create a numerical function which can later be used with scipy.

Comment: Hi, Davide, It seems impossible to find the inverse of a 5th order matrix using symbolic computation.  I tested a simple 4th order matrix and after 10 minutes sympy still gave no results. Can I return "np.linalg.inv(A)*b" in the dydt(t,y) function, thus avoiding the need to compute the inverse matrix symbolically?

Comment: You can give it a try. You would have to compute the inverse for each iteration with `np.linalg.inv(A)`

Comment: @Davide_sd Thanks. I understand that the calculation may be inefficient,  I'll try it soon. I would appreciate it if you are interested in this issue and would like to give it a try, I would love to know how the masters do it.